# Target="_blank" opening in old window

Tags: javascript, html

I have an asp.net 2.0 website. On one page - let's call it "P1", I have a button that opens a new window using javascript - let's call the new window "P2".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openMapEditor() {
            var editor = window.open('<%= Page.ResolveURL("~/imgmap/MapEditor.aspx") %>', '', 'scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=965, height=800');
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                if(editor.closed) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    __doPostBack('','');
                }
            }, 1000); 
        }
    </script>
...
<asp:Button ID="cmdEditMap" runat="server" CssClass="cmdbutton" Text="Upload Image" OnClientClick="openMapEditor(); return false;" />
```

Clicking on the button opens an actual new window in Chrome as I had hoped.

In the new window, I have a link to open another page.

```
<a name="img_href_check" href="http://facebook.com/fn" target="_blank" onclick="return (new RegExp('^https?://+')).test(this.getAttribute('href'));">Check</a>
```

What I was hoping was that the page would open in a new tab in P2, but what actually happens is that it is opened in a new tab P1.

How can I make it so that the page opens in a new tab in P2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't open a new tab/window from a tab/window that was opened via JavaScript.

Comment: Are you saying you can't open it within the new window? Because it opens in the old window.

Comment: I'm saying you cannot spawn a new tab/window by clicking a link with target="_blank" in a tab/window that was spawned via JavaScript.

Comment: You can, however, intercept the click event in JavaScript and open a new tab/window that way.

Comment: I just tried the js route, but it is behaving the same way - it is opening a new tab in the old window.

Comment: I must have misunderstood your original question, as what you're seeing with JavaScript handling the click is what I would expect.

Comment: Going back to the old days (for me), you can call a function on the parent window passing the href of the link in order to spawn a new window like you've done in openMapEditor, but that will result in 3 windows, not a new tab on the second window.